# String match of only 3 specific words

Tags: java, regex, string, match

I want  a regex to match a string that only has the words A,I and D without any order or sort

also:if the string has a letter thats not any of these then doesnt go into the if

I have tried with || and other symbols but still cant get it

Doesnt have to be a regex Im just trying to find a way to solve it

```
String message = "AIDDDAAIDAAA"
if(message.matches("(A|D|I)")){

         System.out.println("Matches");
}
```

Comment: all 3 letters or any? `AAAA` or `IIIDDDI` would both be a match or not?

Comment: yes even only full of As can be valid

Comment: You do know that `A`, `I`, and `D` are *letters*, not *words*, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use include all characters you are interested in within a square bracket. To match one or more occurrences of these characters in square brackets, append `+` to it. The `message` string should be entirely made up of only these characters for it to be considered a match.

Try this.

```
String message  = "ADAIAIAIAIAIADDDAI";
if(message .matches("[ADI]+")) {
    System.out.println("Matches");
}
```

Comment: Using *charset* here is misleading - character classes aren't charsets. Also, you might want to add that the expression in `matches()` should match the entire string.

Comment: Yes, I realized charset will be misleading, changed to characters instead.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're asking about "words", I guess `A`, `D` and `I` stand for words with more than one letter and that that is the reaason why you're not using the character class `[ADI]`. You just have to add a `+` because the `message` consists of more words.

```
    String message = "AIDDDAAIDAAA";
    if (message.matches("(A|D|I)+")) {
        System.out.println("Matches");
    }
```

scigs answer works as well.

Comment: Pretty sure `(A|D|I)+` is directly equivalent to `[ADI]+`. I can't think of any string which would match the former but not the latter.

Comment: @Vasan A, D and I seem to be placeholders for words.

Comment: Gotcha. Yes, then it makes sense.

Comment: they arent placeholders,I want that string with really only those words

Answer (score 0):

You could use string replace to do something similar:

```
String message = "AIDDDAAIDAAA";
message = message.replace("A","")
    .replace("I","")
    .replace("D","");
if (message.equals("")) {
    //do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check each char composing the String:

```
String message = "AIDDDAAIDAAA";
boolean matches = true;
for (int i=0; i<message.length(); i++;){
    if (message.charAt(i)!='A' && message.charAt(i)!='I' && message.charAt(i)!='D'){
        matches = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (matches) System.out.println("Matches");
```